# Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request.

Tags: email, outlook, mapi

My application does mapi.MAPIInitialize.
Mapi.MAPIInitialize fails on machines where Outlook is not installed and gives pop up that requires user action.

I want to understand if there any parameters in mapi.MAPIInitialize or way through API to suppress this popup.

I dont prefer to delete any registry to suppress this pop-up.

I am unable to post screenshot of pop up Please check below message
***Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request.  Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.*Microsoft Office Outlook***

Answer (score 2):

You need to avoid loading mapi32.dll from the Windows folder. You must load msmapi32.dll - look at the [MFCMAPI](https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) source code to see how that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Streblechenko.